# cannot open tiff files compressed in this fashion (2) - imageJ/FIJI

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, imagej

I have two sets of images generated from MATLAB - one set is when I save manually from the figure window into a tif file and the other set has images saved in tif format by using `imwrite` function in MATLAB.

When I try to use the first set of images to perform some operations in Fiji (Image J) it works but when I try doing the same on the second set, I get an error saying 'cannot open tiff files compressed in this fashion (2)'. Is there a plugin that I need to install?

imfinfo for first set - created by saveas tif from figure window:

```
Filename: [1x68 char]
              FileModDate: [1x20 char]
                 FileSize: 51376
                   Format: 'tif'
            FormatVersion: []
                    Width: 719
                   Height: 477
                 BitDepth: 24
                ColorType: 'truecolor'
          FormatSignature: [1x4 double]
                ByteOrder: [1x13 char]
           NewSubFileType: 0
            BitsPerSample: [8 8 8]
              Compression: 'PackBits'
PhotometricInterpretation: 'RGB'
             StripOffsets: [69x1 double]
          SamplesPerPixel: 3
             RowsPerStrip: 7
          StripByteCounts: [69x1 double]
              XResolution: 96
              YResolution: 96
           ResolutionUnit: 'Inch'
                 Colormap: []
      PlanarConfiguration: 'Chunky'
                TileWidth: []
               TileLength: []
              TileOffsets: []
           TileByteCounts: []
              Orientation: 1
                FillOrder: 1
         GrayResponseUnit: 0.0100
           MaxSampleValue: [1x3 double]
           MinSampleValue: [0 0 0]
             Thresholding: 1
                   Offset: 50592
         ImageDescription: [1x22 char]
```

imfinfo for second set - created by imwrite. imwrite(bw,fullfile(filename),'tiff');

```
 Filename: [1x75 char]
              FileModDate: [1x20 char]
                 FileSize: 25586
                   Format: 'tif'
            FormatVersion: []
                    Width: 832
                   Height: 587
                 BitDepth: 1
                ColorType: [1x9 char]
          FormatSignature: [1x4 double]
                ByteOrder: [1x13 char]
           NewSubFileType: 0
            BitsPerSample: 1
              Compression: [1x8 char]
PhotometricInterpretation: [1x11 char]
             StripOffsets: [66x1 double]
          SamplesPerPixel: 1
             RowsPerStrip: 9
          StripByteCounts: [66x1 double]
              XResolution: 72
              YResolution: 72
           ResolutionUnit: 'Inch'
                 Colormap: []
      PlanarConfiguration: 'Chunky'
                TileWidth: []
               TileLength: []
              TileOffsets: []
           TileByteCounts: []
              Orientation: 1
                FillOrder: 1
         GrayResponseUnit: 0.0100
           MaxSampleValue: 1
           MinSampleValue: 0
             Thresholding: 1
                   Offset: 24868
```

Comment: Can you show the `imwrite` statement used to generate those images?

Comment: imwrite(bw,fullfile(filename),'tiff');

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, if you got the answer yet. I had a similar problem. Try saving your file via:

```
imwrite(bw,fullfile(filename),'tiff', 'Compression','none');
```

or try compression using 'packbits'

```
imwrite(bw,fullfile(filename),'tiff', 'Compression','packbits');
```

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin for ImageJ - [IJ Plugins: Image I/O](http://ij-plugins.sourceforge.net/plugins/imageio/index.html).

---

**EDIT**

It look like your image is binary (BitDepth=1). IMWRITE by default saves binary image in TIFF format with `ccitt` compression. Such images are not supported by IMageJ. (See, for example, this [thread](http://imagej.1557.x6.nabble.com/Problem-opening-TIFF-image-in-ImageJ-td3684014.html) for a possible reason).

If you need to save your images with `imwrite` try to set `BitDepth` to 24 and `Compression` to `packbits`. Compare other fields in `imfinfo` outputs and use different ones in `imwrite` if necessary.

Comment: Can you open these images outside of MATLAB? Please also show `imfinfo` output for those images. Please update your question if you will have additional information.

Comment: Yeah I can open them. Please check out imfinfo. I updated it in the question.

Comment: Compression parameter to packbits in imwrite seems to be working (I don't get the previous error) but now it says:java.io.EOFException
IJ.openImage() returned null: C:\Original Image data\Input Images\71578-sample2.tif. Am I doing something wrong? I now have binary tif images from MATLAB saved as tiff in the compression supported by Image J but what does 'returned null' mean?